# Нужен совет по Android Java

Tags: java, android

Есть приложения в которым люди выставляют публикации в день один раз.

Нужно как то в приложении ограничить их в выставлении публикаций. Даже не знаю как это реализовать.

Смог бы сделать на сайте в базе, но у меня задача сделать именно ограничения в приложении.

Если есть какие нибудь учебники, публикации или сами сталкивались с этим то пожалуйста поделитесь.

Answer (score 7):

Правильное решение - при старте приложения делать запрос на сервер, который будет сообщать делался ли пост за сегодня. Или даже лучше при каждой попытке залить пост на сервер, он будет возвращать ошибку "лимит исчерпан"

Если в приложении - в момент успешной отправки поста на сервер писать в `SharedPreferences` флаг, который говорит, что сегодня пост был залит. Но это решение можно хакнуть почистив данные приложения или через рут поменять. вариант с сервером намного надежнее.

Да и сами подумайте, у человека два телефона. с одного он пост залил. как второй телефон без сервера узнает что пост уже был залит? Никак. в итоге сколько у человека девайсов, столько он постов в день и может заливать

UPD: Получение IMEI самым простым способом

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String deviceIMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Но лучше почитайте [статью на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/27109/) или [вот еще на английском](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-retrieve-an-unique-id-to-identify-android-devices-6f99fd5369eb) и [статью от Google](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

Comment: просто в приложении нету авторизации и все что знает сервер о юзере это айпи который легко поменять с помощью VPN

Comment: ну у телефона есть еще imei он то не меняется.  но опять таки проблему с множеством девайсов вы не решите. вернее такой проблемы даже нет. поскольку у вас нет авторизации, то клиентом по сути является телефон, а не человек

Comment: крутая идея с имей) есть о чем задуматся. если знаете как правильно вывести имей то буду блогадарен)

Comment: дополнил свой ответ

Comment: `IMEI` отсутствует у девайсов без телефонного модуля. К тому же для доступа к нему `Requires the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.`

Comment: Самый лучший вариант, на мой взгляд, это `ANDROID_ID`, как в блоге по последней ссылке написано.